# Logo image isn't showing up on mobile site but shows up on desktop site

Tags: html, css

I am using the [Minimaxing template](https://html5up.net/minimaxing) to build my website. I changed it so that the logo in the Nav bar so it's a picture of my logo. It shows up nicely on desktop, but it does not show up on mobile. If it was simply text rather than an image, it shows up perfectly fine as displayed in the Minimaxing template website.

All of my code is essentially the same as that in the original but I added the below code to "index.html"

```
            <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <header id="header">
                                    <img class="logo" id="logo" src="C:\Users\test\Desktop\html5up-minimaxing\images\logo.png" width="250">
                                <nav id="nav">
                                    <a href="index.html" class="current-page-item">Homepage</a>
                                    <a href="twocolumn.html">Test1</a>
                                    <a href="twocolumn2.html">Test2</a>
                                    <a href="onecolumn.html">Test3</a>
                                    <a href="threecolumn.html">Test4</a>
                                </nav>
                            </header>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the below code to "main.css"

```
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 30px;
    visibility: visible;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 28px;   
}
```

The actual template has a lot more code that I can't fit on this page, but I will add the code that I think pertains to the mobile nav bar.

```
/* Nav */

        #page-wrapper {
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
            -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
            padding-bottom: 1px;
        }

        #titleBar {
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008dab, #007294);
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008dab, #007294);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008dab, #007294);
            background-image: linear-gradient(top, #008dab, #007294);
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
            -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
            display: block;
            height: 44px;
            left: 0;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 10001;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            background-color: #007294;
        }

            #titleBar .title {
                line-height: 44px;
            }

            #titleBar .toggle {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 80px;
                height: 60px;
            }

                #titleBar .toggle:after {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 4px;
                    top: 4px;
                    color: #fff;
                    text-align: center;
                    line-height: 31px;
                    font-size: 0.8em;
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 35px;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0px 6px 13px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
                }

                #titleBar .toggle:before {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 20px;
                    height: 30px;
                    background: url("images/mobileUI-site-nav-opener-bg.svg");
                    top: 16px;
                    left: 19px;
                }

                #titleBar .toggle:active:after {
                    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                }

        #navPanel {
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-transform: translateX(-275px);
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-275px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(-275px);
            transform: translateX(-275px);
            -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
            -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            left: 0;
            overflow-y: auto;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 275px;
            z-index: 10002;
            background: #00536F;
            color: #fff;
            box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

            #navPanel .link {
                display: block;
                color: #fff;
                border-top: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
                border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                height: 55px;
                line-height: 55px;
                padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

                #navPanel .link:first-child {
                    border-top: 0;
                }

                #navPanel .link:last-child {
                    border-bottom: 0;
                }

        body.navPanel-visible #page-wrapper {
            -moz-transform: translateX(275px);
            -webkit-transform: translateX(275px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(275px);
            transform: translateX(275px);
        }

        body.navPanel-visible #titleBar {
            -moz-transform: translateX(275px);
            -webkit-transform: translateX(275px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(275px);
            transform: translateX(275px);
        }

        body.navPanel-visible #navPanel {
            -moz-transform: translateX(0);
            -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            -ms-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
        }

}
```

If there is more code that you think needs to be shown, you can find it by downloading the template.

Answer (score 0):

The logo img is not showing up on the mobile site because the logo image is stored on your local C drive, not on the server.

```
<img class="logo" id="logo" src="C:\Users\test\Desktop\html5up-minimaxing\images\logo.png" width="250">
```

Upload your image on your image hose server, and replace the local image path with the url.

for example:

```
<img class="logo" id="logo" src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png" width="250">
```

*if you don't have any image hosting service, here's the link about
[how to host your image using google drive.](https://blog.usejournal.com/host-static-images-for-your-apps-or-website-on-google-drive-hotlink-to-gdrive-images-358d6fcf8ef7)

Comment: But why does it show up on the desktop site?

Comment: Did you tried fixing the value for the img tag? I found that for now it's just '250' not '250px' or anything. Also the reason why the logo shows up on your desktop is because, as I mentioned in my answer, the logo image is stored in your desktop which is the only device your 'src' path will work. If you want the image to show up on every other devices, you need to upload the image on the server and set the correct path like "./images/logo.png" or insert the direct image url.

Comment: oh. for the mobile version i just made the window small. I think theres something in the CSS that makes it so that the image does not show. If i didn't put an image as the logo but just some text, then it would show up on mobile.

Comment: Just wondering but do you know what the <img src=" "> does? Also I took an extra step, downloaded the entire html/css and took a look, and it seems like you deleted h1 tag that was originally there and inserted img tag instead. Also if you want the mobile version of this website maybe use @media and make it responsive.

Comment: I am new to HTML, so its very possible i made some mistakes. I think the img src just adds an image. If you can, can you show me what a working code would look like? Thanks!

Comment: so img tag doesn't just adds an image, it brings an image from the whatever path you've provided, either from your hard drive or somewhere on the internet (from the server). 
 Here's the reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: I'll try to post another answer and fix them to the working code later in the weekend if I find some spare time.